# Why is my fourth order Runge Kutta method not accurate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, python, runge-kutta-methods

```
def runge_kutta(f, x0, dt, T):
    n = int(T / dt)

    t = np.zeros(n + 1)
    if isinstance(x0, (int, float)):
        x = np.zeros(n + 1)
    else:
        neqns = len(x0)
        x = np.zeros((n + 1, neqns))
    x[0] = x0
    t[0] = 0

    for i in range(n):
        t[i + 1] = t[i] + dt

        k1 = np.dot(dt, f.f(x[i], t[i]))
        k2 = np.dot(dt, f.f(x[i] + 0.5 * k1, t[i] + dt / 2))
        k3 = np.dot(dt, f.f(x[i] + 0.5 * k2, t[i] + dt / 2))
        k4 = np.dot(dt, f.f(x[i] + k3, t[i] + dt))

        x[i + 1] = x[i] + np.dot((1/6), (k1 + 2 * k2 + 3 * k3 + k4))

    return x, t
```

This is what I wrote for a fourth order Runge Kutta method, but when I test it with a function it showed a high degree of inaccuracy (much higher than what I got for my forward Euler method), which leads me to believe that there is some mistakes in my code. Here is what the Runge Kutta (3 different step sizes, in dotted lines) in action against the exact solutions (solid line) [image: Test Function Results]

Could someone help me on what is wrong in my code?

Comment: This may be the culprit: you have $3k_3$ when, I believe, it should be $2 k_3$ instead.

Comment: @NapD.Lover That is it! Now the approximations are basically the same as the exact function. Thank you so much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the cause of the error is a typo in a standard algorithm.